# can't get xscreensaver GUI to work

Tags: xscreensaver

I have downloaded and installed the xscreensaver source code but I can't get to xscreensaver-demo to set it up. here's everything in a video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xxg5SpIrv08&feature=youtu.be

I am running ubuntu 18.04
I installed xscreensaver the way i did so that i would have the newest version.

Comment: Please do not refer to videos. Questions should be self contained and all information should be in the question itself.

Comment: It isn't always part of the package.  Check to see if xscreensaver-demo is actually on your system.  On mine, it's in /usr/bin, but if it isn't there on yours, search root for it.  What DE are you using?

Comment: sorry i reffered to a video, i wont do that anymore.

Comment: Im running GNOME, and i couldnt find xscreensaver-demo in /user/bin or root. so if it's not always part of the package, then what should i do? thanks for the help :)

Comment: Where did you get xscreensaver from (Ubuntu repository, developer's site, etc.)?  What's in Debian's repository might be really old, but Ubuntu's ought to be recent enough.  Before you mess with source code, try just installing from Ubuntu's respository if that isn't what you did before.  If Gnome has a built-in screensaver settings manager, it could be that xscreensaver-demo was excluded because it conflicts.  If that's the case, you might need to disable what Gnome provides (just guessing).

Comment: BTW, if you "address" comments with @username, the user will get an alert to the posting.  Otherwise, they might be aware of it only if they happen to stumble across it.

Comment: @fixer1234 thanks for the tips :) I got it from the developer's site. I uninstalled what I got from the source code and installed it from Ubuntu's repository, although they last updated xscreensaver about 3 years ago. I like to be super up to date, but I think this will do for now. thanks so much for the help!